# Issue with optional nullable parameter

Tags: asp.net-web-api

One of the endpoints of the API that I work on contains an optional nullable parameter provided by query string.

The endpoint is defined similar to the following example:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("nullable")]
public IHttpActionResult GetAnonymousTypeDefinition([FromUri]long? i = null)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

A contrived and functionally useless example I admit. However, when I run this example locally and in my "dev" environment, it returns `200`. However, when this code is run in my "test" environment it returns a `500` and I'm provided the following error:

> Could not load type 'System.Nullable`1' from assembly 'Example.API,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Just to ensure that my test environment was running a version of the framework that has support for nullable types, I added another endpoint that returns `Environment.Version`, like so:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("framework-version")]
public IHttpActionResult GetFrameworkVersion()
{
    return Ok($"{Environment.Version}");
}
```

The above endpoint returns the following value:

> "4.0.30319.42000"

At this point I'm kind of at a loss as to what else I should check.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there was an issue with how Instana's  IL-rewriting process handles `Nullable<T>`. We provided a quick fix as soon as we were aware of the problem and knew what happened.

This being said I strongly recommend contacting our support-team to get a quick response and let us know about any issues with our components.
The fix has been confirmed and will be released within the next 24 hours.

If you want to get the fix prior to that, contact the support-team and we will provide the patch to your team.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that we were evaluating Instana in our test environment.

One of our ops guys did the following:

Uninstalled the Instana agent and rebooted, then...

Removed Instana related registry keys from:

```
hklm/software/Microsoft/Fusion/GACChangeNotfification/default
hklm/software/microsoft/tracing/instana*
hklm/software/wow6432Node/microsoft/tracing/instana*
```

And unregistered the following DLLs:

```
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Instana\instana-agent\data\repo\com\instana\agent-windows-extensions\1.3.1\agent-windows-extensions-1.3.1\tracing\Instana.Profiler_x86.dll"
regsvr32 /u "C:\Program Files (x86)\Instana\instana-agent\data\repo\com\instana\agent-windows-extensions\1.3.1\agent-windows-extensions-1.3.1\tracing\Instana.Profiler_x64.dll"
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem with Instana. This afternoon we received two new dll's for the Instana agent. After replacing these and restarted the agent everything started to work again. Instana will release a new version of the agent that fixes this issue.